# Control theory: What is the relationship between the number of elements in your system, and your diff'eq IO model and the dimension ABCD Matrix?

Tags: control-system

From my understanding, the order of your system is directly proportional to the number of elements in your system.

Suppose I have a circuit containing 6 capitors/inductors

Then the order of my model is 6

To write the relationship in a differential equation, I need:

$$y^6 + a_1 y^5 + a_2 y^4 + a_3 y^3 + ...+ a_6 = u^6 + b_1 u^1 ... +b_6$$

In terms of ABCD matrices

A is of dimension 6 (i.e. a 6x6 matrix)

Can someone verify whether my understanding is correct?

Comment: Well, it really depends in what you mean by elements. If you have energy storage elements like caps. & inductors, then you can form a state space model with a state variable for each storage element, but you can't necessarily write this as a single ODE. In addition, although this is more a theoretical concern than a practical one, the model need not be minimal. If you have delays, then the state space is more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your circuit can be described as a set of linear first order differential equations, and that it is a single input, single output (SISO) system. With this assumption the system can be written in a state space form as:

$$\dot x = Ax + Bu$$

and

$$y = Cx + Du$$

where x is the state vector, u is the input, and y is the output. A is the 'system' matrix that determines the dynamics of your electrical circuit. B is the input coupling vector. It determines how the input is coupled to your set of state equations. C is your output coupling vector, and it determines how the system states are coupled to the otput. Finally D is your feedforward coupling factor (a scalar) that determines how (or if) the input is directly coupled to the output without dynamics.

Now to answer your question. By expressing your circuit in terms of a finite set of N linear first order differential equations you you are said to have an N-state system, and A will be N X N, B will be N X 1, C will be 1 X N and D will be dimension 1.

The system dimension is not equal to the number of elements or to the number of energy storing elements (e.g. Capacitors and Inductors) but rather the minimal number of first order linear differential equations that can describe the system. Another way to figure this is to write any set of differential equations to describe the system and count the number of integrators (not differentiators). That will give you the order (dimension) of the system.

The same reasoning can be applied to a MIMO (multi input, multi output) linear state space system where B, C are more generally matrices.

Comment: I think there is a distinction between the order of the physical system, the order of the mathematical model, and the minimal order of the mathematical model. Right?

Comment: @SubaThomas Certainly. At the far extreme one could fabricate internal states that are both unobservable and uncontrollable and have no relevance to the physical system in terms of the input-output behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the system is the number of integrators in the system. For a mathematical model this translates to the number of initial conditions needed to integrate the model. Thus for a standard state-space model like the one you describe the order is the number of states in the state-space model. This is different from the minimal order. The two agree if the model is both controllable and observable. (Also if you had something like \$e \dot{x}=a x+b u\$, where \$e\$ is singular, then the order is not equal to the number of states, but if \$e\$ is nonsigular then the order is the dimension of the \$a\$ or \$e\$ matrix.)

Let me clarify this with an example. Consider the system described here (http://wolfram.com/xid/0cf1p1u1v56jj3n-uex790), and I am going to assume that \$L=C R_1 R_2 \$. The physical system has two integrating elements and the state-space representation (ssm) also has two states to reflect that. The order in both cases is 2. However it is not controllable and so the system can be simulated or realized with a lower order system. A minimal realization has \$a=-\frac{1}{C R_1}\$ and \$b=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{R_2^2}+1}}{\mathcal{C} R_1}\$. Thus the minimal order is 1.

To summarize an answer to the question in the title. Given a physical system with N elements, the order of the **physical system** is N. The order and minimal order of the **mathematical** state-space model will be N if you can choose your states to be controllable and observable. For the **mathematical** diff eq, if you take the Laplace transform and if no poles and zeros can be cancelled then the order and minimal order is N. (The latter analysis in terms of simple poles and zeros does not scale well for multivariable systems. The best way to analyze this very generally is to look at the system matrix model of Rosenbrock http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_system_matrix.)